# Spring MVC chat application display online users in realtime

Tags: java, spring-mvc, activemq-classic

I have a spring mvc chat application with a Client A and B. What I want to accomplish is how should I display Client B active users to Client A in realtime. Is using ActiveMQ **Topic** the right aproach or is there another better way to implement this?

Comment: I don't know ActiveMQ but you could use Javascript EventSources. They are not too difficult to implement with SpringMVC.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Thanks for the advice. I have read allot of articles and tried out some examples and I found it easy to implement this by using WebSocket(SockJS/STOMP) and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: Sure, websockets (bidirectional) are the level above eventsources (unidirectional). They require a bit more configuration on the server side to open the ports. Eventsources were more adapted if you just needed a list auto-refresh. websockets are more polyvalent.